# Why does c++ have this rule:Explicit instantiation definitions ignore member access specifiers: parameter types and return types may be private

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

According to this rule, C++ can directly destroy encapsulation under safe syntax

c++11

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
  A() = default;
 private:
  int data_ = 0;
};

template < int A::*Member >
class Access {
 public:
   friend  int GetPrivateData(A& obj) {
     return obj.*Member;
  }
};

template  class Access<&A::data_>; // explicit instantiation

int GetPrivateData(A& );


int main() {
  A obj;
  GetPrivateData(obj);

  return 0;
}

//https://www.zhihu.com/question/521898260/answer/2876618819
```

c++17

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int num) : data_(num) {};
 private:
  int data_ = 0;
};

template <typename PtrType>
class Access {
 public:
 inline static PtrType ptr;
};

template <auto T>
struct PtrTaker {
    struct Transferer {
        Transferer() {
            Access<decltype(T)>::ptr = T;
        }
    };
    inline static Transferer tr;
};

template class PtrTaker<&A::data_>; // explicit instantiation

int main() {
  A a{10};

  int b = a.*Access<int A::*>::ptr;
  
  return 0;
}

//https://www.zhihu.com/question/521898260/answer/2876618819
```

The two implementations have slightly different principles. The former can be regarded as exploiting linking vulnerabilities, but the latter is indeed a completely standard implementation.

And this syntax cannot be checked by a simple keyword search, because there will be a lot of normal explicit instantiation to confuse.

Comment: can you provide a reference for the *rule*? Is it from the standard?

Comment: Assuming this isn't a compiler bug... so what? There are plenty of ways to break encapsulation, both legally and via reliable UB. `private` is meant to stop accidental misuse, not deliberate perfidy.

Comment: I would expect to find it here, but I didnt find it yet. https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#:explicit-instantiation. I think apart from the "hey I can break encapsulation" which isnt really a surprise, this is still an interesting question, but not when its not clear what "rule" you refer to exactly

Comment: " ... parameter types and return types may be private"  ?!? No return types are private here. Return type is `int` and paramter is `A`. I suspect the title is just your attempt to explain why the code compiles. In any case you should clarify where you got that rule from

Comment: @NicolBolas
Can you tell me, if possible, is there any other way to break encapsulation under safe syntax.Another rule is not to modify the original type, not to repeat the definition of the original type.

Comment: Specializing member function template is one more perfectly legal way, here you are: https://godbolt.org/z/WEPGE8Gb4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you are referring to is specified in [[temp.spec.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.spec.general#6)

This rule has been there since C++98, so since the first standardization of C++. It is not somehow new with C++17.

The rule is also necessary. Suppose you wanted to use `Access<&A::data_>` *inside* `A`, where `A::data_` is accessible, but you then don't want `Access<&A::data_>` to be implicitly instantiated, only explicitly instantiated in a single translation unit. Because the explicit instantiation declaration cannot appear inside `A`'s scope, there can't possibly be any check on accessibility. It would make such an explicit instantiation completely impossible.

The same applies to explicit and partial specializations as well.

That you can use additional techniques such as friend injection to then access the private member is not a problem, since these are not things that can happen accidentally. If the user is determined to access a `private` member, then there isn't anything stopping them anyway. (They could for example simply add their own class/function as a `friend` in the class definition, which may or may not be an ODR violation in itself, but will have no negative consequences as such in practice.)

The purpose of access control is only to make it so that the user won't accidentally use a member that they shouldn't use directly and merely instantiating with a private member as argument doesn't allow accessing the private member. That requires additional targeted work. And if a user does all that work to get to the private member, then the user is intentionally breaking the intended use of the class and it will be on them if the result is a broken program.

Comment: And explicit instantiation is merely an optimisation hint anyway; performing it doesn’t allow the programmer to do anything that wouldn’t be otherwise possible, even when restricted to code outside the class written in a memory-safe, free-from-bitcasts subset of C++ (effectively the same subset that is available in `constexpr` context)

Comment: Could you decrypt the mentioned part of the rule: *"parameter types and return types may be private*"? Certainly you guys are not talking about such instance - `A::data_` is not a type. Then what does the *parameter type* pertain to in this rule?
[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation)

Comment: @bloody In the question OP chose a class template explicit instantiation where there is no return or parameter type. They could have chosen something else such as a function template explicit instantiation with a return type naming a private member type. The rule in your link could also include "_template arguments_" in the list, which is what OP uses to demonstrate the lack of access check. However, the actual rule is stated in reverse: Anything lexically inside an explicit instantiation declaration/definition, except as in [temp.spec.general]/6, does not have access restrictions checked.

Comment: Clear, thank you.